# Writing to JS file with ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Is it possible to write info to a JS file in ASP? I know that you can write to txt files, which I've done, but when I try the same method with JS files, it doesn't seem to work. I'm mainly a PHP programmer so I'm used to using `fopen` and `fwrite` to any of those file types and was curious if there's something similar in ASP. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I'm sure it's technologically possible, but there may be better options.

Comment: there is no reason you cannot open a js file and modify the text and save it the same way you di it to a txt file.  Unless of course that file is being used by another program

Comment: Well basically I'm constrained by the Volusion e-commerce framework (which is on a Windows server that doesn't allow PHP; hence the need for ASP) and what I'm trying to do is create functions in jQuery that will run after a user signs up. So essentially, the user signs up, the code sends the info to the Volusion API and puts them in the database but I then need to create page specific Javascript (using location.pathname) that will do things depending on the user's 'username' which is displayed on certain pages. It's kinda convoluted but there's limitations so it's a workaround...

Comment: @QBM5, well what function is it then I'm wondering. I know about this one: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_write.asp but when I try that on a JS file, the page gives me a 500 error.

Comment: A JS file **is** a text file. A browser getting a 500 error means that the developer should read the server logs to find out what the internal server error was.

Comment: You need not write the generated JavaScript to an actual file, you can serve it just like you can serve dynamic HTML

Comment: @flup the problem is that this needs to be saved for the future. It's going to basically be a new 'rule' for the site that needs to be saved.

Comment: You really should give us the bigger picture here, I think. Perhaps it's a cunning plan but it without context it seems odd to put this rule in js only.

Comment: @flup that's ASP.NET, it's very different from classic ASP and can't be dupe target.

Comment: @MxmastaMills not sure what you want from us. As others said, .js file is a text file. It's not encoded, it's not binary, it's written as plain text. As it stands, your question is off topic for Stack Overflow. If you will add what you tried, share your code and your errors, maybe we can help.

Comment: @ShadowWizard alright, retracted.

Comment: @flup thanks, worst case I can Reopen instantly with my hammer, though it still needs to be closed due to lack of information.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I understand that but the 'CreateTextFile' and the other functions that can alter a TXT file through FTP or on the server do not work on JS files. I get that they are encoded the same but the function just doesn't work on JS files which I need it to.

Comment: @MxmastaMills it works. Something is wrong with your specific code or server setting, so if you will tell us what error you get maybe we can help.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok thanks. That's where the confusion was. I wasn't getting any errors, it just wasn't writing to the file so my assumption was that ASP couldn't write to JS files which was the basis of my question. I'll dig deeper and see if I can pull out some error codes during the processing.

Comment: Use FSO or ADODB.Stream to write text file. File name or extension name is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit weird, but I am going to try and answer it for you in 3 different ways and perhaps then you can choose what fits your scenario.  In the future try to be as detailed as possible.

1. If you are asking if you can use JavaScript as the scripting language for your ASP pages, versus using Vb Script then the answer is yes.  ASP can work with a few languages including Perl, and JavaScript (Jscript).   You need to declare it on top of your asp page, and stick to that language for the whole page (cannot mix languages).  <%@ Language= "Javascript" %>
2. If you are asking if you can create physical files with .js extensions on the server, then that answer again is true.  You use the FileSystemObject to create these physical files, and write lines which have JavaScript code.  You want to make sure you completely close your file streams and FSO objects.  Good practice is to write to a temp location, then copy to production location when writing is done (all via FSO methods).   The biggest challenge you will run into with this type of coding is IUSER permissions for the directories you are trying to write files to.  FSO is great for writing logs, but probably should not be used to generate javascript.
3. If you are looking to create Dynamic Javascript you have a few options.   You could go into IIS and let IIS know that .js files should be handled by asp.dll.  THis means files requested with .js extension would be run through the whole ASP pipeline and code with <% blocks %> would be run.   Alternately, if you can have a .asp extension for your javascript file.  For example if you want to create the following user variables from database you could do something like this.

   ```
   <%
   ```

   Response.Clear()
     Response.ContentType = "text/javascript"

   dim UserID 
     UserID = "Frank1979" ' Get this from a database or whatever.

   ' write out as javascript variable for use on client side.
     ' This will create a global js variable named UserID with value of frank1979 
      Response.Write "var UserID = " & lcase(userID) & ";"

   %>